# I need help converting between the let form and unnamed procedure form

Tags: forms, scheme, procedure, let

im trying to convert from a let-form to an unamed procedure form and i just can't get the hang of it.

the let procedure is this.

```
(define max-recursive (lambda (lst)
      (if  (null? (cdr lst))
           (car lst)
           (let ((m0 (car lst))
                 (m1 (max-recursive (cdr lst))))
                 (if (> m0 m1)
                     m0
                     m1
                 )
           )
      )))
```

and what i've done so far is this

```
(define max-recursive (lambda (lst)
      (if  (null? (cdr lst))
        (car lst)
((lambda (m0 m1)
   (if (> m0 m1)
       m0
       m1
      )
   )
   car lst (max-recursive (cdr lst)))
      )))
```

any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it! only a couple of parenthesis were missing around the expression `car lst`. Try this:

```
(define max-recursive
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (null? (cdr lst))
        (car lst)
        ((lambda (m0 m1)
           (if (> m0 m1)
              m0
              m1))
         (car lst) ;here was the error
         (max-recursive (cdr lst))))))
```

The explanation is as follows. A `let` form like this one:

```
(let ((x 10))
  x)
```

... is just syntactic sugar for a `lambda` expression applied to some parameters. The previous `let` is equivalent to this:

```
((lambda (x)
   x)
 10)
```

Notice that in both cases the value `10` ends up bound to a variable named `x`, and the body of the `let` expression is the same as the body of the `lambda` expression

Comment: Thank you but i figured it out just a few minutes after posting.