# I don't understand lambda in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lambda

Can someone please explain how lambda works in scheme? For example how it works here:

```
(define (prepend-every prefix sent)
  (every (lambda (wd) (word prefix wd)) sent))
```

Or here:

```
(define (first-last sent)
  (keep (lambda (wd) (equal? (first wd) (last wd))) sent))

> (first-last '(california ohio nebraska alabama alaska massachusetts))
'(OHIO ALABAMA ALASKA)
```

Answer (score 4):

The special form `lambda` is an anonymous procedure, in the examples shown it's a shorthand to avoid defining a separate one-shot function. For example, the first snippet is equivalent to this:

```
(define (helper wd)
  (word prefix wd))

(define (prepend-every prefix sent)
  (every helper sent))
```

But why define a new procedure that's going to be used only once? that's why we use `lambda` in this case. Also, it's good to remember that a function definition written like this:

```
(define (f x)
  <body>)
```

… Is just a shorter syntax for this equivalent form:

```
(define f
  (lambda (x)
    <body>))
```

So you see, in the end all procedures in Scheme are `lambda`s under the hood. There are other special forms that can get transformed to `lambda`s, for example `let`, `let*`, etc. take a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10018917/201359) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16698686/201359) for further clarification.

Comment: @user2925892 I updated my answer and explained a few more details

Comment: Huh, for whatever reason, the OP's account is no longer existent. I guess they won't be able to accept your answer.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young a one-shot user asking about one-shot functions. How appropriate :S